# Unity 5: Game view - Run Time - SpaceBar Causing Issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

[Game View- Camera Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OVOz.jpg)

When I click the Space Bar for the player to jump, the Display drop down menu pops up and the player doesn't jump. However, the player can move upon all key presses.

Here's the information that I have:

1) Everything worked and functioned properly.

2) I added a health bar to my boss.

3) I created a second canvas (First canvas was for my Player's HP).

4) I made the Boss HP bar render mode: World Space.

5) I attached the canvas to the boss controller in the hierarchy as a child.

6) The code I use for Player Jump is Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space).

7) The mouse curser is inside the Game View whilst testing the SpaceBar Jump.

8) I'm developing in Unity 2018 5.3 2D mode.

**Official Question('s):**

1) Why does the Spacebar causing the camera display drop menu to appear?

2) How do I fix this?

Edit / Additional Content:

Here's my Jump script

```
 public float jump1 = 5.0f;
 private bool onGround;
 //private bool dblJump; //Not implemented yet

 public Rigidbody player;

 void Start () {
    player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    onGround = true;


  }

  // Update is called once per frame
  void Update () {


    if (onGround == true) {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))// KeyCode.Space
        {

                player.velocity = new Vector3(0, jump1, 0);
                onGround = false;
           // Debug.Log("The onGround is False");



        }           


    }     

   }
```

Keep in mind that I have temporarily changed my jump to LeftShift. However, my problem persist with the space bar, even when I click it with left shift as my jump. SpaceBar seems to summon the drop down menu for the camera display. (I can't seem to catch the drop down menu with a screen shot because it goes away upon a click)
Also Note - I'm inside a class called PlayerJump : MonoBehavior.

[image: The Boss character, the Boss canvas, the Yellow back ground image, and the blue foreground Filler image]

[image: Boss Canvas Render settings(Inspector)]

[image: Boss With enlarged HP bar so you can see that it is attached and works]

Comment: I *think* this has to do with the Unity Editor hotkeys. It's [a known issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/disable-editor-keyboard-shortcuts-while-playing), but you can try [this suggestion](https://www.reddit.com/r/Unity3D/comments/36z8f4/disable_editor_keyboard_shortcuts_in_play_mode/) to get around it (if this is one of those things).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the insight! I can actually use this suggestion for another idea I have. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it's a known issue with some versions of Unity 5.3, I have a few solutions you can try :

- Drag you game window somewhere else in the editor
- Enable the "Maximise on play" button
- Attach this script to your drop-down element :

  ```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;
  using UnityEngine.UI;
  using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

  public class DropdownScript : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler {

   void Start()
      {
          dropDown = GetComponent<Dropdown>();
          dropDown.interactable = false;
      }

      public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData ped)
      {
          dropDown.interactable = true;
      }

       public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData ped)
      {
           dropDown.interactable = false;
      }
   }
  ```

Otherwise update you Unity version if it's not the latest release? I am not experiencing this issue but many other users are apparently.

Comment: Yes, I'll be happy to do these things for you. Please allow me to figure out the best approach. I'm new to this site and I am trying to learn how to traverse it. I tried to paste the code inside of this comment, but it was too long by characters. I'll try editing my OP and see if that works. Thank you for your time! (Also note- I temporarily made LeftShift my jump so if you see that KeyCode.LeftShift, I commented KeyCode.Space next to it. The left shift works, but the SpaceBar issue still remains.)

Comment: Let me know if I need to add anymore content for you to see.

Comment: I dragged my Game window into an un-docked position and now the SpaceBar doesn't come down anymore! I have tested it with both, the LeftShift and the Spacebar and the problem seems to be resolved! I do thank you for your help! Hopefully this helps other's encountering the same issue!

Comment: Good to know one of the options worked, glad to have been helpful =)